# Can parent node property be updated internally based on property changes of a child node in a graph database?

Tags: database, database-design, graph, database-schema

How can I do this internally in Neo4j or ArangoDB Graph?

properties:

```
child_node1: color:red
child_node2: color:blue
child_node3: color:blue

parent_node1: color:red:1,blue:2 ; size:3
```

relationship:

```
child_node - member_of -> parent_node
```

if 
`child_node1: color:blue` 
then: 
`parent_node1: color:blue:3 ; size:3`

Comment: Is Neo4j 3.0 available and do [stored procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_user_defined_procedures) qualify as "internal"?

Comment: yes for both questions.